# Set default path for Angular auxiliary route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink, angular-auxiliary-routes

so I have this setup . It sets the default path for left-router the ExploreAllComponent as you can see. I want the first routerLink to direct to the outlet's home path, but this way it's not working. I've tried with '/', but it isn't working too.

**Routing**

```
 {
    path: '',
    component: ExploreAllComponent,
    outlet: 'left-router'
  },
  {
    path: 'exploreNews',
    component: ExploreNewsComponent,
    outlet: 'left-router'
  }
```

**Html**

```
<li [routerLink]="{outlets: {'left-router': ''}}" routerLinkActive="active">All</li>
<li [routerLink]="{outlets: {'left-router': 'exploreNews'}}" routerLinkActive="active">News</li>
```

Comment: Try `[routerLink]="[{outlets: {'left-router': ''}}]"`

Comment: Not working too. ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''